# Tkinter query to SQLite Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, tkinter

When querying a SQLite DB to display the elements using Python TKinter using the following line of code:

```
self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())
```

The values from the last column are not displayed. The result I get if I select one of the rows is this:

```
{'text': 'Samsung S10', 'image': '', 'values': ['700.0'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

I can see the name (Samsung S10), the price (700.0) but not the stock.

So this line of code:

```
self.tabla.item(self.table.selection())['text']
```

Will display the name of the product. This next line:

```
self.table.item(self.table.selection())['values'][0]
```

Will display the price. But I cannot see the way to display the column stock.

In SQLite Name is configured as `Text`, `Price` as `Real`(float) and I have tried configuring Stock as `Real` or `Integer`, making no difference at all.

I tried the same code as before but putting, 1 instead of 0.

```
self.table.item(self.table.selection())['values'][1]
```

But I was getting the error message

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

[image: Screenshot of SQLite DB]

It is the Treeview widget I forgot to mention that.

Actually I came across the answer. When I am querying the DB to display it I must access "values" as an array like this

```
self.table.insert('', 0, text=row[1], values=(row[2], row[3]))
```

Being row[2] and row[3] the price and the stock. Then we can retrieve those values with the code that follows:

```
self.table.item(self.table.selection())['values'][0]
self.table.item(self.table.selection())['values'][1]
```

Comment: If `self.tabla` is a `ttk.Treeview`, then how do you create it and how do you populate data into it? You should provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you’re talking about a treeview widget, so

```
self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())
```

return a dictionary that represent the selected row.

```
{'text': 'Samsung S10', 'image': '', 'values': ['700.0'], 'open': 0, 'tags': ''}
```

In this dictionary the key values has only an item so if you try to select 1

```
self.table.item(self.table.selection())['values'][1]
```

you get right

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

cause values key has only an item.